# CentOS/Redhat: Systemwide aliases when logging in through LDAP/sssd

Tags: centos, redhat, ldap, sssd, aliases

I've asked this question in the Centos Support forum, but we didn't found a solution for it (https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=46101#p196728)

When logging in through LDAP/sssd, we didn't found a way to set up system-wide aliases for all users which are activated when logging in with ssh as well as with the graphical window manager:

- Editing `/etc/bashrc` and adding the alias to the bottom yields no success at all. Neither while using ssh nor graphical login.
- Editing `/etc/profile` and adding the alias there yields only a success while using ssh

I know that editing these two files are a bad idea. It would be great if someone has a solution which loads scipts in `/etc/profile.d/*`

Enviroment:

- Clients: CentOS 6.5
- Server/LDAP: OpenLDAP/slapd 2.4.31-1+nmu2 on Debian 7

Answer (score 1):

On my CentOS box the reason that `/etc/bashrc` is loaded is because a) my shell is bash and b) my personal `~/.bashrc` sources /etc/bashrc.

Does the .bashrc that users get provisioned with when their home directory is set up include sourcing /etc/bashrc and is /bin/bash the default shell in your LDAP?

It could be that the variables/aliases you're trying to modify are also set in the .bashrc or .bash_profile files in the users home directory, negating any attempts to set systemwide defaults/overrides?

That leads to the second question: How are home directories created? E.g. on the client with pam_mkhomedir at first login or are home directories created centrally on your Debian server and for example exported over NFS? The Debian default ~/.bashrc which is copied from /etc/skel when a home directory is set up may differ from the CentOS template in /etc/skel which sources `. /etc/bashrc`.

---

**Edit** in response to Noxx's comment below:

According to the bash man page the *only* global file loaded by bash is:  `/etc/profile` *The systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells* .

That fits with your observation that changes made there have effect when you login using ssh.

That one has by default a section that recursively loads the `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` files which should be the drop in location for custom files with aliases and such.

I think (but do not have the means to test now) a graphical login does not start a login shell only a window manager and it may be that the bash shell you get in for example a xterm window is although interactive not a login shell.

Again from the man page: *When an interactive shell that is not a login shell  is  started,  bash  reads  and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.* No other/global configuration files are loaded.

RHEL/CentOS address that and make interactive shells similar to login shells by sourcing /etc/bashrc in the personal `~/.bashrc`

Your best may well be to deploy such a .bashrc when you set up user accounts.

Comment: Shell is set to /bin/bash and the user's .bashrc is beeing read.
No manual sourcing in .bashrc is done as the global one should be loaded automatically. Home-dirs are created centrally and exported over NFSv3. If the user adds the alias in his .bashrc it works but the goal is to provide a global list of already set-up aliases which can be changed whenever I like.